# Problems retrieving XML with Python requests

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am probably overseeing something obvious but I can't seem to figure it. I am trying a simple verification to start with using the following url.

http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml

http://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api#verifycred

(Here's the full documentation regarding this URL).

This is the code used for testing it out.

```
class Foobar():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        client = requests.get('http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml',
            auth=(username, password))

        if client.status_code == 200:
            print "Succesfull authentication. %i"%client.status_code
        else:
            print "Authentication failed %i"%client.status_code

    print client.text

Foo = Foobar()
Foo.bar()
```

I got a correct response once and assumed this was the right way of going. However from this part on I only receive responses like this.

[image]
Every request send regarding the user credentials being correct or not.

I've tried various encoding and neither have affected the response in any way.

EDIT: I seem to have solved the issue. After wiping my cookies and clearing my cache it returned a valid response by status code 401.

Comment: have you tried using a xml parser to parse the response content?

Comment: The XML parser cannot parse the returned HTML.
header['Content-Type] returns text/html

Comment: OK, then have you tried putting content-type to xml on headers before sending your requests? like so: `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}` `client = requests.get('..', headers=headers, ...)`?

Comment: I found the issue see: edit. I had tried that as well. But some cookies most likely caused it to not work. If I found out which cookies specifically I will add it because they had 21 cookies by the time I removed them.

Comment: ok your case is not reproducible from others because the site requires auth credentials. What we can help is to provide some general guidance. Please update if you have any progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue causing it was cooking placed by the site itself. I am unsure which cookies specifically caused this problem but once found I will add it.

EDIT: They have a bot checking thrid party connections which bans you upon trying to connect rending their API useless.